# How to make SharePoint fields mandatory conditioned on other fields?

Tags: visual-studio, custom-form, column, form, validation

For example, in a workflow task, I might have a master field called "Approve" which, if set to "No", makes it unnecessary to complete the rest of the form (and thus makes them non-mandatory). Is there a clean way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instances like that, in the past I've marked all the fields optional in the list then created a custom new/edit form and included jQuery and PreSaveAction() to do my own logic.

I'd have the Approve column visible with everything else hidden.  If they select no, then they can save the form with nothing else required.  If they select Yes, then the remaining hidden fields become visible.

Comment: But the user will still be able to submit the form without completing the fields, won't he?

Comment: You can use validation logic on the form fields.  I've used PreSaveAction() in the past to force validation on optional fields that I want to make mandatory based on conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on how you implement the forms in the fields. If you customize them with InfoPath, you can use conditional formatting to make fields mandatory by using rules. You can set a rule like: If Field1 = "yes" then Field 2 cannot be blank. This would make it mandatory based on the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Visual Studio/ASP.NET. I should have specified it in the question.